# How to setup a domain class to get my response from RestTemplate?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am new with RestTemplate so I am looking for some help with the creation of a domain class that will get the response using RestTemplate. The JSON structure that I get calling the url looks like this

```
[{
        "id": "2",
        "name": {
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Smith"
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "123 Main St",
            "city": "Perth",
            "state": "GA"
        }
    },
    {
        "child": {
            "info": {
                "firstname": "Bob",
                "age": "12"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "child": {
            "info": {
                "firstname": "Jessica",
                "age": "22"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "child": {
            "info": {
                "firstname": "Robert",
                "age": "9"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "child": {
            "info": {
                "firstname": "Beth",
                "age": "9"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I understand I need to create classes to handle the structure
I created one class for the first part {}

```js
class FirstPart {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String address;
}
```

then the other parts are repeating (same structure and I can get 0,1 or more {}). How can I create my structure to be able to get the response? I believe I need a class that will containg all the structure (I will call it Principal)

so my post will include the url, the body and the Principal.class

.....

```js
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Principal principal;
    principal= restTemplate.postForObject(url,requestBody,Principal.class);
    return principal
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the JSON format fixed? reason is that it cannot be parsed using jackson in a straight forward way. It looks like it contains json objects of different type: _List<Principal|Child>_ (read List of Principal or Child).

Comment: hi, the JSON format is not fixed. The"child" part can vary.

Comment: check out how you can use jackson to deserialize polymorphic collections (e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)

alternatively you could use a custom deserializer (https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

Do as below and small modification in JSON :

```
public class InfoDto{
    private String firstname;
    private Integer age; 

    //getters & setters
}

public class ChildDto{
    private InfoDto info;

    //getters & setters
}
public class AddressDto{
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;

    //getters & setters
}

public class UserDetails{
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    //getters & setters
}

public class RestResponseDto{
    private Long id;
    private UserDetails name;
    private AddressDto address;

    private List<ChildDto> childs;

    //getters & setters
}
```

JSON

```
[{
        "id": "2",
        "name": {
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Smith"
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "123 Main St",
            "city": "Perth",
            "state": "GA"
        }
    },
    childs:[{
        "child": {
            "info": {
                "firstname": "Bob",
                "age": "12"
            }
        }
    },
   ...............
    .............
    ...................
   ]
]

 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    RestResponseDto principal;
    principal= restTemplate.postForObject(url,requestBody,RestResponseDto.class);
    return principal
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion!. The only problem  is that I can't modify the json file.